# OutOfMemoryError while compressing a picture

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, compression, out-of-memory

I am working on an application that at a certain point has to compress a picture in order to send it to the server. If the compression doesn't work, it sends the non-compressed photo (not a big deal).

Despite the compression method is surrounded by a try-catch it sometimes throws an OutOfMemory error on a few devices and I want to avoid it.

This is the method:

```
fun compressCapture(
    capture: File
): ByteArray? {
    return try {
        val compression = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().getLong(Constants.PICTURE_QUALITY)
        val pictureBytes = capture.readBytes()
        val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(pictureBytes, 0, pictureBytes.size)
        val outputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, compression.toInt(), outputStream)
        outputStream.toByteArray()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            Crashlytics.logException(e)
        null
    }
}
```

*If it returns null the application sends the non-compressed file*

The stack trace that I am receiving in Firebase sometimes is that:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 1735832 byte allocation with 1549160 free bytes and 1512KB until OOM
       at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:122)
       at com.sagacollect.utils.FileUtils.compressCapture(FileUtils.java:9)
```

Otherwise is that:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 51916812 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 45MB until OOM
       at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(VMRuntime.java)
       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java)
       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:561)
       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:591)
       at com.sagacollect.utils.FileUtils.compressCapture(FileUtils.java:9)
```

Any idea of what could be happening?

Cheers, Mauricio

Comment: `val pictureBytes = capture.readBytes()`. Why dont you send these bytes? What do they contain exactly? A bitmap?

Comment: They haven't been compressed yet

Comment: "They haven't been compressed yet" -- then what format are they in? You are using `BitmapFactory` to decode them, so they are in some image format, and most supported image formats are compressed (e.g., JPEG, PNG, WebP).

Comment: You should check the image size before trying to read and compress it, it is not really a good idea to catch a OutOfMemoryError because if anything is allocated... well, your app can freeze and get stuck.

But anyway, the reason your app crashes instead of catching the OutOfMemoryError is because you are catching `Exception` while the `OutOfMemoryError` is an `Error`.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your VM has run out of memory. You could try adding

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

to your manifest.xml file and see if that solves the problem. It's not recommended as a permanent solution unless really necessary, but might help you troubleshoot.

There are image loading libraries that you can use like [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/), [Coil](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/) or [Glide](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html) that will better help with compression issues.